# Загрузка Spring Boot на Hekoru

Tags: java, spring, heroku, boot

Когда запускаю в идеи сервер стартует без проблем, при попытке загрузить на heroku через git вылазит ошибка

```
 To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
       Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing
       > Task :compileJava FAILED
       
       FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
       
       * What went wrong:
       Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
       > Could not target platform: 'Java SE 14' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.
       
       * Try:
       Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
       
       * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
       
       BUILD FAILED in 32s
       1 actionable task: 1 executed
 !     ERROR: Failed to run Gradle!
       We're sorry this build is failing. If you can't find the issue in application
       code, please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com
       You can also try reverting to the previous version of the buildpack by running:
       $ heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-gradle#previous-version
```

Мои поиске решения проблемы мне ничего не дали, может у кого было похожее?

Comment: `> Could not target platform: 'Java SE 14' using tool chain: 'JDK 8 (1.8)'.` ?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду

Comment: в сообщении написано, что ваш сервис разработан для 14 версии java, но на сервере он пытается скомпилироваться под 1.8 версию. JDK версии 1.8 не может собрать проект, разработанный для JDK 14

Comment: Нужно мануально указать версию java на 14 (см: https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1749)
Ну либо понизить версию java в проекте до 8 (если код и зависимости позволяют)

Answer (score 0):

Решение было снижение версии java c 14 на 1.8(8)